# 'Android Package Builder' builder - output filename?

Tags: android, eclipse, environment-variables, apk, builder

Is there a way to get the output filename from the 'Android Package Builder' step when run in Eclipse?

I created a custom builder step that runs after 'Android Package Builder' and I have to hard-code the apk filename. The first problem, which is minor, is that I can't reuse the step between projects (I have a library project and several projects). The second, larger, problem is that this doesn't work when the application is exported, because the destination path for the apk is totally different.

Is there a variable that is set by the 'Android Package Builder' step, or any of the previous steps, that I can use in my custom builder? Something along the lines of ${project_path}?

Answer (score 1):

I dug through `android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml`, and it looks like `${out.packaged.file}` is likely the variable you're looking for?